# Outsourcing some software development tasks

Tags: software-industry, communication, team, project-management

We currently have a development team of 5 people and a support team of 8.
We are based in Ireland and are doing ongoing software development on a product we license and support to a number of customers.

We are currently considering linking with an outsourcing company and in tandem increasing our development team in Ireland.

I have a contact who is very well known and respected in the industry who has an outsourcing team based in India.

I've an initial meeting with him soon to discuss this, and these are the points for my agenda.

- **Experience:** Type of projects your company have done before Available resources
  (expertise and costs)
- **Communication:** (e.g. daily stand ups, communicating progress during the day, instant messaging etc, what time will outsourced team be available from to, what about weekends etc)
- **Source control:** (e.g. we would expect code to be checked in daily to our TFS)
- **Code Review:** (e.g. making sure code is TDD and developed to our standards)
- **Code ownership** (our company will own the code)

It is also my view that the outsourced devs, would work strongly with my devs (e.g. on the same projects, doing code reviews etc).

I like a list of other things to discuss during this initial meeting before committing so we can avoid any common pitfalls.

Comment: How about approaching a lawyer to draw up a contract ?

Comment: I don't think we are at the stage of spending money on contracts before having initial discussions and seeing what the company offer.

Comment: @Deferm a contract lawyer that deals with outsourcing will be able to inform you of exactly the sort of common pitfalls that you are interested in.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about outsourcing development to another company and is not a Workplace SE topic. Please see [help - topic](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for the topics our site can help with.

Comment: Disagree that this is off topic. How to successfully outdource is a genuine workplace problem.

Comment: I disagree too, I think how to work with outsourcing companies is an absolute workplace problem.

Comment: I think this is off-topic because the breadth of the question reads to me like "how do I do this particular aspect of my job", which is off topic.  Also, "a list of other things to discuss" to me is a poll, also not a good fit for SE.  More focused questions on this topic overall _can_ be a good fit for Workplace.SE, but I agree with this particular closure.

Comment: mmm I was just looking a list to discuss during initial meeting, I was looking a wide guidance of things to do ongoing.

Answer (score 5):

I would also suggest asking them to come onsite for a few days or weeks.

Reason being, you want to make sure that their team and your team have some time to get acquainted.  I've found it is far easier to work with someone who I have met in person vs someone I have not.  Especially when that person is in another country, several time zones away, and that is from a different culture.

You will also want to check their bill rates, and probably compare them against others in India.  If they are very low, that should be a red flag.  Likewise if they are very high.

Comment: Thanks Alan, I was actually thinking of going out to visit them, as I want to see their setup, and meet face to face.